# Select distinct result

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have mongodb collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51111618b419e37023f5070c"),
    "checkCode" : "statusCode",
    "checkDate" : ISODate("2013-02-05T18:24:24.927Z"),
    "domain" : ObjectId("511102021ffae419c2363c33"),
    "pageUrl" : "/index.html",
    "checkResult" : "404"
}
```

The collection can has many records with same domain, pageUrl, checkCode but different checkResult (or the same) and different checkDate (date of the check).

So I need to select only last by date checkResult by pageUrl and checkCode in given domain. What is the best and faster way to do this (there could be lots of records by domain and check results) ? Should I use group or map/reduce? Distinct works too slowly...

Comment: You could use the aggregation framework here: `db.col.aggregate([{$match:{domain: ObjectId("511102021ffae419c2363c33")}},{$group: {_id: {pageUrl: '$pageUrl', checkCode: '$checkCOde'}, checkResult: {$max: '$checkResult'}}}])` maybe that is something close to what your looking for? I am unsure what you mean by "last" unless you were to sort your incomnig documents by something

Comment: @Sammaye last by date. Is there any way to do this without aggreagate function?

Comment: Not if you intend to group, in SQL you would also do this with a group so in MongoDB it is the same unfortunately.

Comment: I think I should use $max with checkDate field to find out checkResult last by date.

Comment: You can but you can also do you match and then add a $sort as another pipeline and then get the $first or $last of that sort, i.e. if you sort DESC on the timestamp you would get the $first of the sorted group. This means that your sort and match can use an index

Comment: @Sammaye I think about that. I will test what will work faster. You can post this in answer and I'll vote for it. Thanx!

Comment: Done glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the aggregation framework here like so:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match:{domain: ObjectId("511102021ffae419c2363c33")}},
    {$sort:{checkDate:-1}},
    {$group: {_id: {pageUrl: '$pageUrl', checkCode: '$checkCode'}, checkResult: {$first: '$checkResult'}}}
])
```

Using the `$match` and `$sort` with the `$first` operator allows for index usage which could make a performant group for at least a substantial number of records.